# How do I interpret this pseudocode in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, pseudocode

I don't quite understand how to "initialize a multidimensional array to equal 1" as the initial for loops seem to suggest here. I haven't learned to properly read pseudocode, and I don't fully understand how this program works.

```
function countRoutes(m,n)
  grid ← array[m + 1][n + 1]

  for i = 0 to m do 
    grid[i][0] ← 1
  end for

  for j = 0 to n do 
    grid[0][j] ← 1
  end for

  for i = 1 to m do
    for j = 1 to n do
      grid[i][j] ← grid[i − 1][j] + grid[i][j − 1] 
    end for
  end for

  return grid[m][n] 
end function
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @CarySwoveland : I think only the first row and column are initialized with 1.

Comment: Note: It's one of those examples where Excel is a much better tool than Ruby :D

Comment: The answer is `(m+n) choose m`, by the way. `(m+1..m+n).inject(1,:*)/(1..n).inject(1,:*)` should do. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636128/calculating-the-number-of-possible-paths-through-some-squares

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't hard to translate.. Ruby uses `=` instead of left arrow for assignment, and `def` instead of `function` to define a subroutine (which it calls a method instead of a function), but that's about it.  Let's go through it.

```
function countRoutes(m,n)
```

That's beginning a function definition. In Ruby we use a method instead, and the keyword to define such a thing is `def`. It's also convention in Ruby to use snake_case for multiword names instead of camelCase:

```
def count_routes(m, n)
```

Now to create the grid:

```
grid ← array[m + 1][n + 1]
```

Ruby arrays are dynamic, so you don't normally need to specify the size at creation time. But that also means you don't get initialization or two-dimensionality for free. So what we have to do here is create an array of m+1 arrays, each of which can be empty (we don't need to specify that the sub-arrays need to hold n+1 items).  Ruby's Array constructor has a way to do just that:

```
  grid = Array.new(m+1) do [] end
```

Now the initialization. Ruby technically has `for` loops, but nobody uses them. Instead, we use iterator methods.  For counting loops, there's a method on integers called `times`. But the pseudocode counts from `0` through `m` inclusive; `times` also starts at `0`, but only counts up to *one less* than the invocant (so that way when you call `3.times`, the loop really does execute "three times", not four). In this case, that means to get the behavior of the pseudocode, we need to call `times` on `m+1` instead of `m`:

```
  (m+1).times do |i|
    grid[i][0] = 1
  end
```

As an aside, we could also have done that part of the initialization inside the original array creation:

```
  grid = Array.new(m+1) do [1] end
```

Anyway, the second loop, which would be more awkward to incorporate into the original creation, works the same as the first. Ruby will happily extend an array to assign to not-yet-existent elements, so the fact that we didn't initialize the subarrays is not a problem:

```
  (n+1).times do |j|
    grid[0][j] = 1
  end
```

For the nested loops, the pseudocode is no longer counting from 0, but from 1. Counting from 1 through m is the same number of loop iterations as counting from 0 through m-1, so the simplest approach is to let `times` use its natural values, but adjust the indexes in the assignment statement inside the loop. That is, where the pseudocode starts counting `i` from 1 and references `i-1` and `i`, the Ruby code starts counting `i` from 0 and references `i` and `i+1` instead.

```
  m.times do |i|
    n.times do |j| 
      grid[i+1][j+1] = grid[i][j+1] + grid[i+1][j] 
    end
  end
```

And the `return` statement works the same, although in Ruby you can leave it off:

```
  return grid[m][n]
end
```

Putting it all together, you get this:

```
def count_routes(m, n)
  grid = Array.new(m+1) do [1] end

  (n+1).times do |j|
    grid[0][j] = 1
  end

  m.times do |i|
    n.times do |j| 
      grid[i+1][j+1] = grid[i][j+1] + grid[i+1][j] 
    end
  end

  return grid[m][n]
end
```

Comment: I am getting an error message: " undefined method `−' for main:Object "
...presumably for the nested loop. I tried defining i and j to no avail. Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: The original version of my answer had some off-by-one errors due to my misinterpreting the way the pseudocode `for` loops work; double-check against the latest code above.

Comment: Ruby code seems to work fine here. No error messages. Not sure exactly what routes we're counting, but `count_routes(3,5)` returns 56.

Comment: Instead of `Array.new(m+1) do [1] end` you can just write `[[1]] * (m + 1)`

Comment: @akuhn nope, that gets you m+1 references to *the same array*, so any change to one will change all.

Comment: Also true in Perl (with `x` operator) and Python, FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

The notation `grid[i][j] ← something` means assigning `something` to the element of `grid` taking place on `i`-th line in `j`-th position. So the first two loops here suggest setting all values of the first column and the first row of the grid (correspondingly, the first and the second loops) to 1.